# jquery ajax does not parse json on failure

Tags: jquery

jQuery's jqXHR object passed to the callback on failure does not parse json responses, therefore responseJSON is undefined only responseText is available.

It works fine for successful requests, I am setting the correct headers using `dataType: 'json'`

Call:

```
  $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: $form.attr('action'),
    data: post_data,
    dataType: 'json',
    done: done_callback,
    fail: fail_callback,
    always: always_callback
  });
```

Request Headers:

```
Accept:application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01
X-Requested-With:XMLHttpRequest
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_6_8) AppleWebKit/535.11 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/17.0.963.83 Safari/535.11
```

Response Headers:

```
Content-Type:application/json;charset=utf-8
Status:500
```

responseText:

```
{"status":"error","code":500,"message":"A system error occurred, please try again later"}
```

responseJSON is undefined

**Is it the case that jQuery does not parse json when the response to ajax requests is unsuccessful?**
*I cannot find any documentation to confirm or deny this behaviour (I could be just not looking hard enough)*

I can obviously just use `parseJSON` in the `fail` callback.

Comment: You're right. The response content is not `eval`ed on error. If you're receiving JSON on 500 errors just parse it yourself.

Comment: yes. @Arun quite rightly pointed me to the exact line that jquery have taken this decision not to pass the response through the type converters.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I had a look into the jQuery ajax callback method. It does the `dataType` conversion only if `( status >= 200 && status < 300 || status === 304 )` is true; otherwise the response is passed, as such, to the corresponding handler. That is, if the request is a failure then the response is not parsed as per the expected `dataType`.

If you want more info you can look for the above condition in the jquery.js file and see it working.

Comment: Indeed, you're spot on. Do you have any idea why jquery has this specifically coded in, seems very strange, response data is valid even for errors. HTTP1.1 says "Except when responding to a HEAD request, the server should include an entity containing an explanation of the error situation"

Comment: I think it is because they assumes that if the request is a failure then the response contents may not be dependable

Comment: This is no longer true: http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/13917#comment:2 "*As of this commit: […] parsed JSON is available in case of failures as the responseJSON field of the jqXHR instance.*"

Comment: @Ashe / Amelia The comment in that ticket you're referring to appears to be inaccurate. If you scroll up a bit in the commit message linked from the ticket comment, it [becomes obvious](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/commit/eebc77849cebd9a69025996939f930cbf9b1bae1#diff-c3749d3acba09ca9ec16bb56e496408bR609).

Comment: @jpaugh: (a) we're talking about 5 year old code here, just to be clear. (b) it's not obvious to me? [The test case](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/commit/eebc77849cebd9a69025996939f930cbf9b1bae1#diff-aa898f7876bea8233bf8cce67b18e4a2R1381) looks pretty clear.

Answer (score 1):

Since version 1.5 of jQuery there is statusCode handler added:

```
$.ajax({
  statusCode: {
    404: function() {
      alert("page not found");
    }
  }
});
```

However in earlier versions you should parse the response text separately when error status is returned:

```
$.ajax({
  success: function(response) {
    data = $.evalJSON(response);
    alert(data);
  },
  error: function(response) {
    data = $.evalJSON(response.responseText);
    alert(data);
  }
});
```

Comment: I think the native function is parseJSON not evalJSON, I get: "evalJSON is not a function" using jQuery 1.11.0

Answer (score 0):

I guess what you are looking for is `data.status` and `data.statusText`

Comment: a "data" object is not passed to failure callbacks, only success, I want my json as an object

Comment: That would be new to me, the app I build in the moment a webapp with round about 100 ajax calls and I use in every single one  'error: function (data) {
                    alert("data: " + data.status + " " + data.statusText);
                }'  I have no problems with it

Comment: data.statusText is exactly that text as defined by HTTP1.1 in my case "Internal Server Error" this is not what I want, I want the actual response object after type chaining, not the XHR object, just like you get in a success callback. eg. `{error:"error",status:500,message:"We are unable to receive your message right now."}`