# How to keep jQuery jqXHR.responseJSON with own converters?

Tags: jquery, ajax, converters

For jQuery 3.2.1 I've responseJSON in ajax errors

```
$(document).ajaxError(function (event, jqXHR, options, jsExc) {
    alert(jqXHR.responseJSON);
})
```

But when I've added custom converter

```
$.ajaxSetup({
    converters: {
        "text json": function (stringData) {
            var json = JSON.parse(stringData);
            ... // some modification
            return json;
        });
    }
});
```

`jqXHR.responseJSON` become undefined (but`jqXHR.responseText` present). So with converters jQuery doesn't
evaluate `jqXHR.responseJSON = JSON.parse(jqXHR.responseText)`.
Is it possible to force them to do this in order to get `jqXHR.responseJSON` in `ajaxError` callback when converters configured?

BTW: according [jquery ajax does not parse json on failure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9821396/jquery-ajax-does-not-parse-json-on-failure) in case error jQuery doesn't convert `responseText` to `responseJSON`, but without converters in my case it does.

UPDATE: it become much easily with second parse parameter:

```
$.ajaxSetup({
    converters: {
        "text json": function (stringData) {
            return JSON.parse(stringData,
                function (key, value) {
                    return ...; // field modification
                }
            );
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: What disappeared?

Comment: Why would you expect responseJSON in error callback in the first place?

Comment: I expect presence of `jqXHR.responseJSON`, as it was without converters.

Comment: What do you have in `responseText`? If it is json  parse the text

Comment: Stop using vague terms like "doesn't happen". Not very clear for a technical problem and doesn't explain what you do have or what you need

Answer (score 1):

Maybe `jqXHR.responseJSON` hasn't been initialized. This can happen if the converter (`function (stringData)`) did not complete its execution due to an error in `some modification` code, and `return json` was not executed.

Comment: Yes:)! Before `each` I need to check `typeof inputJson === 'object'`